# Section and subsection in two languages with Legrand Orange Book

Tags: sectioning, formatting, templates

I to all,

I am using The Legrand Orange Book template for writing a textbook for my students.

In Italy, it is strongly recommended, to insert the title of all paragraph in two languages: Italian and English. For the moment I have used this code that work:

```
\section{Introduzione}
\textit{\textbf{\Large Overview}}
```

with this result:

[image: Result of my code]

The question is this: **I would create a new command like `\section{text it}{text en}` and obtain the same results.**

This for `\section` and `\subsection` and - of course - in the index must appear only the Italian title.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really know where the problem is. The following code gives me the result shown in the image.

[image: giacomoLegrandTemplate]

```
\newcommand{\itensec}[2]{\section{#1}{\noindent\large\bfseries\sffamily\textit{#2}\medbreak}}
\newcommand{\itensubsec}[2]{\subsection{#1}{\noindent\bfseries\sffamily\textit{#2}\smallbreak}}
\itensec{Vombatidi}{Wombats}
\blindtext
\itensubsec{Carpincho}{Capybaras}
\blindtext
```

Note: The spacing after the section title has been amended in `structure.tex`.

---

The solution presented in the other answer works as well.

Comment: +1 Thankyou for your time. I try to insert your code into the template that I have strongly customizated.

Comment: Ok. Your code work fine without any kind of errors. Thankyou again.

Comment: @Giacomo So you are not using the template anymore. In that case you have to present more information to get a reliable answer.

Comment: Yes and no. I using the template, but I have translate it into Italian (an easy operation), I have add same other environments and modified some others. Eventually, I have add several packages that I use for generate, e.g., Karnaugh maps, and remove others that generated some conflicts. But your code work very well. But the template is the same, now in Italian and with a strong orient for technical books.

Comment: @Giacomo If you replace the motor of your car with something different and ask people on the internet how to fix something, they assume the car is unchanged. I of course get your point, but you using the template is completely irrelevant here. The other answer works as well with tge template, but seemingly not with your modifications.

Comment: I know, it is my fault: apologize me. The code is very long and I did not realize that it impact also in two rows of code.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following?

```
\documentclass{book}

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\oldsection[#1]{#1\\ \textit{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A}

\section{Italian title}{English title}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, your commands are simple and pretty but do not work (I have insert it into `structure.tex` file).
If I use them, I obtain a fatal error: the file `main.tex`, make an error in the command `\input{structure}`, where are definites all the parameter, packages, environments and so on.

Comment: Looks like it's interfering with something. I've expanded the code into a minimal working example. Try using that and copy all packages and macros you're using into that example to see where it starts to fail.

Comment: +1 I have tried to put the code also into `main.tex`, but with differen errors. I see that your code work by itself, but I need something that work with The Legrand Orange Book template.