# The Legrand Orange Book: Section

Tags: sectioning, templates

I'm using [The Legrand Orange Book](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book) style and I would like to write section names in rectangle (ocre colour). Please if somebody know how could I do that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Could show with a picture at least for me what would you do precisely?

Comment: Dear Sebastian, here is the link what I would like to do:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381466/section-and-subsection-in-two-languages-with-legrand-orange-book. I would like to write the title of the section in a rectangle of some colour. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: **You have been taken in by a common misconception.  What is referred to on the internet as “LaTeX templates” are in reality other people's documents which are tailored to their specific needs.  Therefore it is close to impossible to perform any modifications on these without breaking the entire thing.  They are really only meant to exchange their content with yours.  Any other adjustment is simply out of scope.**

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390683/why-should-you-avoid-using-complex-templates for a discussion of templates, including opinions contrary to those of @HenriMenke - full disclosure: among others, mine :)

Comment: And @Marlea, please provide a small but complete example document (i.e., code), using the template, with a section name in it (should not be more than 20-25 lines, remove as much as you can, while still retaining a working, compilable document with a section in it - add also a link to `structure.tex`) and we might be able to help you.